# Need to update a string value in XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file in which there is a particular string needs to be updated 
Below in XML File I have "@@key@@"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Movies>
  <Movie name="Ready">
    <Director>John</Director>
    <Download>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**@@Key@@**=relatedreadypart6</Download>
    <Price>$40</Price>
  </Movie>
</Movies>
```

I want to update @@key@@ with some valid Data.

Comment: Look at XmlDocument and XDocument. Then, try some things. It is just using a simple XPath Selector coupled with updating the element Value. Alternatively, just treat the entire file as a string (and use string.Replace or RegExp.Replace) since it seems like a very specialized problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var path = "C:\path\to\file.xml";
var markup = File.ReadAllText(path);
var new_markup = markup.Replace("@@key@@", "foo");

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(new_markup);
```

Load the file as string. Do a simple `.Replace` and then parse it as XML. `new_markup` is a `string` representation of the XML. `doc` is an XML representation of the XML.

Comment: Thanks a lot that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(string.replace(xmlStr, " @@key@@","your data"))
```