# How to loop through xml elements to update one using C#

Tags: c#, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need to update a string value in XML using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096647/need-to-update-a-string-value-in-xml-using-c-sharp)

I have an xml file that look as follow:

```
<MediaContent>
  <PublishInfo region="A"  publishState="NotPublished"  />
  <PublishInfo region="B"  publishState="Published"  />
<MediaContent/>
```

I want to loop throgh elements  so I can update the "publishState" of the region B to "Unpublished". I could only update the publishState of region A.

Can anyone tell me plz how to reach the region B and Update the publishState of this region.

Regards

Comment: whats the question? where is the file? what have you tried?

Comment: You have an error in your input data. Сlosing tag should be `</MediaContent>`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that with [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
// get PublishInfo elements with region B
var query = xdoc.Descendants("PublishInfo")
                .Where(pi => (string)pi.Attribute("region") == "B");
// update elements
foreach (var element in query)
    element.Attribute("publishState").Value = "NotPublished";
// save xml
xdoc.Save(path_to_xml);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got this error

Comment: @user1926689 I didn't suggested you to use `OfType`

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to use Linq2Xml. Include

```
    using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Load your file like this

```
    XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load(@"C:\test.xml");
```

Then check out the "Query your Data" section in this [Link](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/10/understanding-c-simple-linq-to.html)

Comment: thanks I got this erroe;'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XNode>' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and no extension method 'OfType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XNode>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?.   I already included system.Xml.Linq;